# SwaggerUI not generating name attributes for parameters

Tags: php, swagger

I created my `swagger.json` for my PHP REST API using this PHP package:
https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php

However, when attempting to test my API from the Swagger UI, for some reason, the inputs DO NOT HAVE A name attribute and I get a errors:
`Notice: Undefined index: year` and `Notice: Undefined index: make`

**This is the generated HTML when loading my swagger.json:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="parameters">
        <td class="col parameters-col_name">
            <div class="parameter__name required">
                <!-- react-text: 360 -->year<!-- /react-text -->
                <span style="color: red;">&nbsp;*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="parameter__type">
                <!-- react-text: 363 -->integer<!-- /react-text -->
                <span class="prop-format">
                    <!-- react-text: 365 -->($<!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 366 -->int32<!-- /react-text -->
                    <!-- react-text: 367 -->)<!-- /react-text -->
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="parameter__deprecated"></div>
            <div class="parameter__in">
                <!-- react-text: 370 -->(<!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 371 -->path<!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 372 -->)<!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col parameters-col_description">
            <div class="markdown">year to retrieve models for</div>
            <input type="text" class="" title="" placeholder="year - year to retrieve models for" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parameters">
        <td class="col parameters-col_name">
            <div class="parameter__name required">
            <!-- react-text: 378 -->make<!-- /react-text -->
            <span style="color: red;">&nbsp;*</span>
            </div>
            <div class="parameter__type">
            <!-- react-text: 381 -->string<!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
            <div class="parameter__deprecated"></div>
            <div class="parameter__in">
            <!-- react-text: 384 -->(<!-- /react-text -->
            <!-- react-text: 385 -->path<!-- /react-text -->
            <!-- react-text: 386 -->)<!-- /react-text -->
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col parameters-col_description">
            <div class="markdown">make to retrieve models for</div>
            <input type="text" class="" title="" placeholder="make - make to retrieve models for" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**And here is the corresponding section of my swagger.json:**

```
"/API/GetModels": {
    "get": {
        "summary": "Get Available Models",
        "description": "Gets Models available for passed year/make combination",
        "produces": [
            "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
            {
                "name": "year",
                "in": "path",
                "description": "year to retrieve models for",
                "required": true,
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
            },
            {
                "name": "make",
                "in": "path",
                "description": "make to retrieve models for",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "successful operation"
            },
            "500": {
                "description": "Internal error"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

**Here's my annotations in my PHP script:**

```
/**
 *
 * @SWG\Get(path="/API/GetModels",
 *   description="Gets Models available for passed year/make combination",
 *   produces={"application/json"},
 *   summary="Get Available Models", 
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *      name="year",
 *      in="path",
 *      type="integer",
 *      format="int32",
 *      description="year to retrieve models for",
 *      required=true,
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *      name="make",
 *      in="path",
 *      type="string",
 *      description="make to retrieve models for",
 *      required=true,
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Response(response=200,description="successful operation"),
 *   @SWG\Response(response=500,description="Internal error")
 *   )
 * )
 */
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Where exactly do you see those errors? Can you post a screenshot? They shouldn't affect the "try it out" functionality in any way though (e.g. http://petstore.swagger.io also has inputs without names and "try it out" works just fine.)

Comment: Also, the annotations are not quite correct. Since you are using path parameters, the endpoint should look like `/API/GetModels/{year}/{make}` or `/API/GetModels/{make}/{year}`. Or if the parameters are supposed to be passed in the query string, they should be `in: query` and not `in: path`.

Comment: I was unaware of the `query` value for the `in` property.

Comment: @Helen, Post your comment as answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotations do not look right.

Since you are using `in: path` parameters, the endpoint should look like `/API/GetModels/{year}/{make}` or `/API/GetModels/{make}/{year}` – that is, the parameters are part of the URL.

If the parameters are supposed to be passed in the query string, they should be `in: query` and not `in: path`.

To learn more about various parameter types in OpenAPI/Swagger, see [Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/). This guide explains the actual OpenAPI syntax rather than Swagger-PHP annotations, but it should help you get the idea.